# HTML5 number input field with currency symbol in the end of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have a html5 number input field containing the EUR sign, and no matter what editing occurs to the field, for the sign to be persistent. I tried to do that, but the EUR sign won't appear inside the field, I want to move this sign at the end of the input but for some reason, I can't do it. I don't want to remove class form-control.  Any help?

My snippet:

```css
.input-symbol-euro {
  position: relative;
}

.input-symbol-euro input {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.input-symbol-euro:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: "€";
  right: 0px;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
}

.form-control[disabled],
.form-control[readonly],
fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #eee;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<span class="input-symbol-euro">
    <input type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1" class="form-control"  />
</span>
```

Comment: I think the same code to include search button into input field will work here. Google it. If worked post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the `<span>` some sort of useful `display` property so that it will wrap the `<input>`. By default this element has a value of `inline`. In the example below I've used `inline-block`, but `block` would do just fine.

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4tek1ro/8/).

```css
.input-symbol-euro {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.input-symbol-euro input {
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-symbol-euro:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: auto;
  content: "€";
  right: 20px;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
}

.form-control[disabled],
.form-control[readonly],
fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #eee;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<span class="input-symbol-euro">
    <input type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1" class="form-control"  />
</span>
```